# How to apply CountVectorizer to a column of a dataset?

Tags: pandas, sklearn-pandas

I have been able to use the CountVectorizer in single text strings and all but I have a dataset that has 80.000 length. How can I apply CountVectorizer to everything in a single column?
I have tried the following:

```
count_vect = CountVectorizer(lowercase=False)
cv = count_vect.fit_transform(df['Tokenized_Review'])
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Do you mean, to apply the vectorizer for each row in a column ? Or, to aggregate all the rows in a column into a into corpus of text and vectorize that ?

Comment: The first one. I am trying to apply the vectorizer for each row in a column.

Comment: What is the result of that code and how is it different from what you expect? I believe that what you wrote would apply CountVectorizer to every row of the `Tokenized_Review` column.

Comment: It returns, TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, everyone, for your time.
Turns out this will do the trick:

```
df['Vectorized'] = 'default value'
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
for i in range(0,len(df):
    vectorizer.fit_transform(df['Tokenized_Review'][i])
    df['Vectorized'][i] = vectorizer.vocabulary_
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this in a long time, but here's one way I can think of. There might be a more elegant solution after mine.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()

for i, row in enumerate(df['Tokenized_Reivew']):
    df.loc[i, 'vec_count]' = vectorizer.fit_transform(row)
```

I have not tested but I think this will work.

Comment: I get an IndexError for being out of range. It's been a long day to fix it now but this gave me an idea. Thank you.